# Find all values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which the fraction $\frac{3^n-2}{2^n-3}$ is reducible

Tags: number-theory

> Find all values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which the fraction $\frac{3^n-2}{2^n-3}$ is reducible.

**Attempt:**

We find all values of $n$ for which $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ and take the complement. Since $2^n-3$ is odd and $3^n-2$ is odd, we see that $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ is equivalent to $\gcd(6^n-2^{n+1},2^n-3)=1$. We then obtain $\gcd(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1},2^n-3) = 1$ and finally $\gcd(3^{n+1}-6,2^{n}-3)=1$.

This doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

**Original solution:**

We find all values of $n$ for which $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ and take the complement. Since $2^n-3$ is odd and $3^n-2$ is odd, we see that $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ is equivalent to $\gcd(6^n-4,2^n-3)=1$. We then obtain $\gcd(5,2^n-3) = 1$ is equivalent to our required condition. Then since the powers of $2$ modulo $5$ cycle as $2,4,3,1,\ldots$ we see that $\gcd(5,2^n-3) = 1$ occurs only when $n \neq 3+4k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$. Therefore, our solution set is $n=3+4k$.

Comment: It does not look so trivial. If $n=4k+3$, both $3^n-2$ and $2^n-3$ are multiples of $5$. Numerical simulations seem to suggest that otherwise $(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, that actually was my initial solution. I just posted it in; can you try and justify it?

Comment: @user19405892: $4\mathbb{N}+3$ is clearly part of the solution, but where is the proof it is the only part?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It is the only part because I took the complement. Also just look at the cycle of the powers of $2$ modulo $5$.

Comment: @user19405892: if $n=4k+3$ then $\gcd(2^n-3,3^n-2)\geq 5$, ok. But that does not exclude that $\gcd(2^n-3,3^n-2)=101$ (just to say) for some $n\neq 4k+3$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not sure what you are saying, but the solution set according to my solution is $3+4k$.

Comment: @user19405892: why they are **all** the values such that $\gcd(2^n-3,3^n-2)\neq 1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My solution explains it.

Comment: I disagree. It just proves that for every $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3$ the $\gcd$ differs from one, it does not prove the opposite, i.e. that $\gcd\neq 1$ implies $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3$.

Comment: "Find every man shorter than 170cm". You find me: that does not imply I am the only man shorter than $170$ cm.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not using your argument for establishing $n=3+4k$. I am using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I surrender. $\phantom{}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Do you see my argument for why $n = 3+4k$? Do you agree with it?

Comment: $4\mathbb{N}+3$ belongs to the solution set and your proof of it is fine. However, $\subset$ is not the same thing as $=$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So you agree with me that $\gcd(3^n-2^n,2^n-3) = 1$ is equivalent to saying $\gcd(6^n-4,2^n-3)=1$?

Comment: WHERE did you get this problem???????

Comment: "composite" woule be a better word than "reducible"

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824629/prove-that-gcd3n-2-2n-3-gcd5-2n-3.

Comment: @lhf: it is interesting to point out that both questions contain wrong claims. Maybe a question from an ongoing competition?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio certainly contests, however that includes past exams as well as current contest preparation in many countries; also problems from other sites that were not completely answered there, which is the best explanation for the mistaken assumptions. We get a fair amount from AOPS, for example.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How does this question have a wrong claim?

Comment: Your last lines do not prove that **the only** solutions are given by $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3$, they only prove that any $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3$ is a solution.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio There is nothing wrong with the problem and also that is my attempt at a solution. I never said it was correct.

Comment: You still cannot get it? There is nothing wrong in your proof that any $n\in 4\mathbb{N}+3$ is a solution (easy $\pmod{5}$), but your attempt is not a complete proof since it contains an unproved claim, i.e. that **every** solution is of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: Unfortunately the following is not true: If $a,b$ are relatively prime to a prime $p$ and $a^n=b$ (mod p) and $b^n=a$ (mod p) then $ab=1$ (mod p).

Comment: As pointed out by Will Jagy in a now deleted answer, this problem comes from IMO 1972 long list. See IMO compendium, [page 87](https://books.google.com/books?id=W0zWM1jmoS8C&pg=PA87).